# Is the function $G$ on the sequence space $\Sigma$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Here is the space I am working with:

Define a sequence space $\Sigma = \{s_0s_1s_2...\space | \space s_i = 0 \text{ or } s_i=1\} $(each element is an infinite string of $1$'s and $0$'s).

For $s, t \in \Sigma$, define a metric $d$ such that $d[s,t]= \Sigma_{i=0}^\infty \frac{|s_i - t_i|}{2^i}$.

Here is the problem:

For a $s_0s_1s_2... \in \Sigma$, define a function $G$ such that $G(s_0s_1s_2...) = 111...$ if $s_0 = 1$ and $G(s_0s_1s_2...) = 000...$ if $s_0 = 0$.

Is $G$ continuous on $\Sigma$?

So far I have that for $s,t \in \Sigma$ we want to show that:

$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0, 0<d[s,t]<\delta \implies d[G(s),G(t)] < \epsilon$

But I'm not sure how to prove or disprove this discontinuity.

Comment: Try with $\delta < 1$.

Comment: just an observation - your 'metric' does not satisfy the requirement $d(x,y)=0 \Rightarrow x=y$

Comment: I think it does, if the distance is zero, then every term in the series must vanish, i.e. $s_i=t_i$ for every $i$.

Comment: @DavidHolden It does. $d(s,t) = 0$ f and only if $s_i = t_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: what about, eg $d(100000...,0111111...)$?

Comment: @DavidHolden in your example, each bit is different, thus the result is 2, not 0.

Comment: sorry -logic circuit fail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the key is to understand that with this metric, two sequences are close if they coincide in their first terms. The further "down" an entry is, the lesser does it influence questions of proximity.

So, in your question: If you have $\delta< 1$, as Daniel Fischer suggested, you know that the first terms of $s$ and $t$ have to coincide (because otherwise your distance would already be at least one). But then $G(s)$ and $G(t)$ are the same, hence have zero distance wich is smaller than every epsilon.